# Kinesis Firehose load csv data into Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-kpl, amazon-kinesis-agent

I am using Kinesis firehose to process data into redshift and i am trying both Json and Csv formats.

The Json format works fine for me and data is getting loaded into redshift table.

**COPY COMMAND USED FOR JSON :**

COPY products_json FROM 's3://foldername/' CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam:::role/' MANIFEST **json 'auto';**

**CLI Command to put record :**

aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name csvtoredshiftstreamingjson --record='Data="{\"productid\":1,\"productname\":\"phone\",\"productprice\":\"2.30\"}"'

However when i use CSV, data is present in S3 but not loaded in redshift.

**COPY COMMAND USED FOR CSV :**

COPY products_csv FROM 's3://foldername/' CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam:::role/' MANIFEST **csv**;

**CLI Command to put CSV Record :**

aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name csvtoredshiftstream --record='Data="1,Phone,2.30"'

The records are getting processed to S3 but not loaded to redshift. The STL_LOAD_ERRORS table also does not have any records.

Please do let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [the current AWS status page](https://status.aws.amazon.com/) - everything is a bit of a mess but is starting to come back up.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, that is true but the issue i reported is persistent from last week, i believe i am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome this issue by providing firehose access to redshift by unblocking the following Ips in Redshift

52.70.63.192/27 for US East (N. Virginia)
52.89.255.224/27 for US West (Oregon)
52.19.239.192/27 for EU (Ireland)

These Ip addresses are used by firehose to communicate with Redshift.

Thanks & Regards,
Srivignesh KN